# Removing indices from rows in 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array with the shape `(9, 100, 7200)`. I want to remove the 2nd half of the 7200 values in every row so the new shape will be `(9, 100, 3600)`.

What can I do to slice the array or delete the 2nd half of the indices? I was thinking `np.delete(arr, [3601:7200], axis=2)`, but I get an invalid syntax error when using the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error occurs because `[3601:7200]` is not valid python. I assume you are trying to create a new array of numbers to pass as the `obj` parameter for the delete function. You could do it this way using something like the range function:

```
np.delete(arr, range(3600,7200), axis=2)
```

keep in mind that this will not modify `arr`, but it will return a new array with the elements deleted. Also, notice I have used 3600 not 3601.

However, its often better practice to use slicing in a problem like this:

```
arr[:,:,:3600]
```

This gives your required shape. Let me break this down a little. We are slicing a numpy array with 3 dimensions. Just putting a colon in means we are taking everything in that dimension. `:3600` means we are taking the first 3600 elements in that dimension. A better way to think about deleting the last have, is to think of it as keeping the first half.

Comment: Thanks soo much for the thorough response and explanations. I'm still learning Python so I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just slicing?

```
arr = arr[:,:,:3600]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. I'm still new to Python so I appreciate the help